# Specific Getting index of NSMutableArray Problem

Tags: objective-c

I have a bit of a problem in my code, and i'm beginning to wonder if it's a design issue..

I'm treating my appDelegate class as the primary model for my application. With the appDel class, I have a viewcontroller. In my appdelegate class I store an NSMutableArray called blocks which has all of my block object models. Similarly, in my viewcontroller I have an identical NSMutableArray called blockViews which stores all of my block object views. The way I update the view after receiving notifications from the model is through KVO. In my viewcontroller, I observe each location property of each block in my blocks array (in the app delegate), and update the corresponding blockView in blockViews.

I also have it set up so that whenever I add an object to my blocks array in the appDel, it adds an object to the end of the blockViews' array. Now, my problem arises when I try to remove an object from my blocks array (in the appDel class). I will not always be removing the last object, and so I am stuck as to how to get the actual index of the object I am trying to remove so that I can remove the corresponding index in my blockViews NSMutableArray.

In my observeValueForKeyPath method, the object being passed is the appDelegate class because I am observing the entire blocks array from my viewcontroller (I implemented the Indexed Array Accessors to allow for KVO notifications to occur), and because of this the object being passed into observeValueForKeyPath is in fact a reference to my appDelegateClass (which makes sense).

But, from this, I cannot obtain the index of which object was removed from the blocks array. Does anybody have any suggestions as to how I could alter this to provide an index, or a way to get the correct index?

Is there any way to observe an array for additions or removals, AND have the object being passed into my observeValueForKeyPath method be the block that was added/removed itself, instead of the appdelegate class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you use `indexOfObject...` (several variations) to get the index, and then remove it in both arrays?  (You realize that NSMutableArray implements all the methods of NSArray, right?)

Comment: yes, but i can't get that.. i guess this post is hard to follow because there's so much going on.. but that can't be done because I remove the object from blocks array, and I want to remove the object from the blockViews array when the object from the blocks array is removed, but the object being passed into observeValueForKeyPath is a reference to my appdelegate class.. so i can't get the index because KVO doesnt know which object was actually removed, it just knows that AN object was removed.

Comment: Technically, in my observeValueForKeyPath, i could loop through all my objects in my blocks array, checking their locations with the locations of each of the objects in my blockViews, then remove the extra blockView object that doesn't have a corresponding block object.. but that way seems too tedious and unnecessary.

Comment: Why can't you just handle both arrays in the app delegate class?  You apparently know what to remove there.  You can have the app delegate do a notification if you don't want a "hard" connection.  Using KVO for mainline function (vs "observation") seems like doing it the hard way.

Comment: Well the primary reason i put my blocks array in my appdelegate was because I wanted to adhere to MVC. If i put the blockViews in my appDelegate, I feel like that's combining the model with the view.

Comment: I think the ultimate fix is to not use KVO for adding views, and instead just add them manually after i add each block model, and only observing location and updating the view through KVO. Thanks for your input.

Comment: With Objective-C MVC is out the window almost before you start.  Don't get hung up on an artificial structure.

Comment: All obj c is, is Mvc? What is GOING ON

Comment: Yes, the letters M and V and C occur in Objective-C.  But the UI scheme pretty much prevents you from implementing "MVC" in any realistic form.  The "view" and "controller" are intimately entertwined, with the view being basically a passive appendage to the view controller and relying on the view controller to perform all data access.  And generally much of the "business logic" ends up in the view controller as well.

Comment: i agree with you, i find it difficult to implement a good MVC design in most of my apps, and when I do it often leads to difficult design issues to solve (such as this one here). I'm mostly from a c# background so I know OOP, but MVC is slightly frustrating at times.

Comment: MVC is a good concept, at a theoretical level.  But trying to adhere to it often, in real life, produces worse code than without it.  I've seen several really bad designs, done in the name of MVC.